# Why is the alphabetical order breaking in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple rails page showing "projects," which have a title, year, and file associated with them. Here is my controller:

```
# GET /projects
# GET /projects.json
def index
  @projects = Project.all.order(:title)
end
```

And here is index.html.erb:

```
<ul>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <li><a href="<%= project.document.url %>" target="_blank"><em><%= project.title %></em>, <%= project.year %></a>
      <% if logged_in? %>
       <br><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %> / <%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% if logged_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path %><p id="notice"><%= notice %></p></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Using psql (10.3, server 9.6.2) on Heroku

All of the results are in perfect alphabetical order by title, except for the ones called "Spring House," "Springg House, "Springgg House," etc. Other titles using this pattern sort correctly, but for some reason, the "Spring" ones don't.

[image: Screenshot of Rails app demonstrating incorrect order]

Do you have any advice about where I should look in the app to fix this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you also show us the relevant code for the view? (e.g. `index.html.erb`)

Comment: @drosboro yes! apologies for leaving it out.

Comment: Have you checked what your database is doing? Try to run the SQL that you get from "Project.all.order(:title).to_sql" directly from your db management tool.

Comment: 'Spring House' actually looks correct to me. 'G' comes before 'H', unless you are counting on all upper case to come before all lower case. Remember, the ordering is happening on the DB side, and not all DBs use the same rules for alphabetical order. If you want ruby to order the array, try `@projects = Project.all.sort_by(&:title)`

Comment: @JacobVanus I can definitely imagine it going one way or the other, but it isn't consistent, which is what I don't understand—see, for example, "Winter House, Winterr House." It goes from "Wordx Word, Word Word" to "Word Word, Wordx Word"

Comment: @forrest what DB are you using?

Comment: postgresql on Heroku. I'm working on figuring out how to do @neongrau's suggestion now, as I've never done anything to access the database apart from via rails on Heroku before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @neongrau The SQL is: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."title" ASC and it returns in exactly the same order that shows up on the site when I run it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" of how Postgresql handles sorting - and to make matters worse, it varies from database to database, and even from platform to platform.

When you write `Project.all.order(:title)`, Rails generates SQL (as you correctly figured out in a comment above) like this:

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."title" ASC
```

This leaves Postgresql, or whatever other database you're using, to determine the order.  Postgresql uses [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/collation.html) to determine order, which are locale-dependant.  You can see what collations your databases are using by executing the `\l` command in `psql`.  On my machines, for example, my databases default to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Here's where it gets tricky.  I created a table in postgres as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sorttest (name text);
INSERT INTO sorttest VALUES ('Spring House');
INSERT INTO sorttest VALUES ('Springg House');
INSERT INTO sorttest VALUES ('Springgg House');
SELECT * FROM sorttest ORDER BY name ASC;
```

On my Mac (Mac OS 10.13.3), it returns

```
name      
----------------
Spring House
Springg House
Springgg House
```

However, on my Debian machine, it returns

```
name      
----------------
Springgg House
Springg House
Spring House
```

As best as I can tell, the Mac is actually "doing it wrong", although it's the result you want.  My Debian box, and your Heroku dyno, are sorting according to the UTF-8 spec: ignoring whitespace and capitalization, "springgghouse" should come before "springhouse".

If you want to sort using a different collation (say, the "C" or the "POSIX" collation), you need to use a SQL command like this:

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."title" COLLATE "C" ASC
```

Fortunately, you can get there with ActiveRecord:

```
Project.all.order('title COLLATE "C"')
```

However, please note that this will make capitalization matter in your sort order - the "C" collation compares ASCII byte values, so capital letters will sort before lower case, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM sorttest ORDER BY name COLLATE "C" ASC;

name      
----------------
Spring House
SpringGg House
Springg House
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't completely follow it, though—why doesn't this apply to the other records? It seems like only the "Spring" section is acting like your Debian machine, but all the other ones, like "Fall" and "Winter" are acting like the Mac?

Comment: Your solution to being more specific with ActiveRecord works! I'm still curious about the mystery though :)

Comment: Simple... the default sort order ignores spaces - so the last letter of the first word being earlier in the alphabet than the H of house triggers the problem.  “Springg” before “Springh”, so “Springg House” before “Spring House”.  However, “Fallh” before “Falll”, so “Fall House” before “Falll House”.